# Type 'number | number[]' is not assignable to type 'number[]'

Tags: typescript

I got a typescript function which returns an object with a result property which can be either of type number or number[].

Now in another function I want to get the last element of that result array (I know in that case the result is of type number[] but it throws me the following error.

Type 'number | number[]' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.

Why is that the case and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **only** assign an array of numbers.

You have something which **might** be an array of numbers **or** it might be a single number.

You can't assign a single number because it isn't an array of numbers.

You need to test to see which of the two things you actually have and, if it isn't an array of numbers, convert it to one.

For example:

```
const myNumberOrArray = firstFunction();
if (typeof myNumberOrArray === "number") {
    const array = [myNumberOrArray];
    otherFunction(array);
} else {
    otherFunction(myNumberOrArray);
}
```

Comment: To extend this answer with a resource of the official TypeScript handbook, one can read up about type narrowing and type guards. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html